# wp pagenavi not working with category id

Tags: plugin-wp-pagenavi

Can someone let me know i am using wp pagenavi wordpress plugin

http://renegadehealth.com/blog/?cat=6708

When i click on the next button at the bottom the following link comes:-

http://renegadehealth.com/blog/blog/index.php?cat=6708&paged=2

an extra "blog/blog/" is being added

Comment: Whats your permalink structure ?

Comment: Permalink structure is:-
/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a category link built with a question mark?
If you use the correct permalink which is http://renegadehealth.com/blog/herbs
pagination is working fine.

Comment: For the herbs page i am using a page template for publishing all posts in a category.

If i don't use WCS hotfix for displaying category then these does not display.

Comment: If your permalink structure is /%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname% your category link should look like http://renegadehealth.com/blog/category/herbs and should not contain any question marks. Try resaving your permalink structure.

Comment: If you are on a windows server there are some specific permalink recommendations such as adding a index.php to the permalink: /index.php/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/ http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Permalinks_without_mod_rewrite

Comment: Actually Mirage, the question mark is there because i am using WCS hotfix. Earlier the categories were not displaying and i had to use this plugin.

Comment: for some strange reason 

http://renegadehealth.com/blog/blog/index.php?cat=18&paged=2

the above url is having "blog" 2 times instead of:-

http://renegadehealth.com/blog/index.php?cat=18&paged=2

Comment: If there is someway we cannot use hotfix and display categories details page that should also work.

Comment: is there a way to add code in .htaccess file for this so 2 times blog does now come?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are redirecting from renegadehealth.com to renegadehealth.com/blog ? 
How is this redirection done?

Comment: wordpress is installed in the blog folder.

Comment: from what i can see there is some issue with .htaccess that is adding blog 2 times in the above url.

Comment: Can we somehow modify htaccess file for this to work?

Comment: ok, wordpress is in your blog folder. But what is in your root directory that it is redirecting to blog? Maybe this redirection is causing the error. You could install wordpress in the blog folder and put index.php in your root directory. This way you can get rid of the blog directory in your url 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Pointing_your_home_site.27s_URL_to_a_subdirectory

Comment: I used this above suggestion as well but the problem is the same. Is there no way to change:-

http://renegadehealth.com/blog/blog/index.php?cat=2728&paged=2

to:-

http://renegadehealth.com/blog/index.php?cat=2728&paged=2

If you see blog is coming 2 times

Comment: do you have an additional .htaccess in your root folder? How do you redirect renegadehealth.com to renegadehealth.com/blog/ ?

Comment: the site is being redirected to blog folder with simple javascript

Comment: In your permalink settings did you enter anything as category base? What is the content of your .htaccess file?